# Email API service with Sendgrid like API endpoints and Mailchimp like dashboard

Tags: email, mailchimp, sendgrid

We are looking for an email API service that allows us to send emails to specific users (not just list by list but user-by-user). Usually that would be considered transactional email and you would use an API like Sendgrid or Mandrill for it.

However, we have been using the Mailchimp service so far and we really like its dashboard and what it allows you to do from subscribing users manually, to sorting and searching, etc. We also like how Mailchimp handles unsubscribes, subscription confirmation, and preference updating of subscribers.

is there any API service that combines the two?

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid actually has all of the features that you mentioned in your question.  We have a dashboard that will allow you to:

- Subscribe users manually
- Sort and search through your list of users
- Handle unsubscribing

We don't force you to opt people in (subscription confirmation), but that would be super easy to build if you really wanted it.

More details about all of this on our website and in our documentation.  You can also contact our support team (which is available 24/7 by phone, email, and chat)